# rails 6.1.3 using react Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

My app is rendering a blank page The console has the error "Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element." from index.js line 7

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../stylesheets/index.css';
import App from '../components/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('body')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'index.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You should use document.getElementById('root')

Comment: That still gets me the same error

Comment: Your tag responsible for using the index.js has to be below your div not above it

Comment: That solved it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shyam's comment answered my question I needed to put my javascript_pack_tag below the div tag in my index.html file